# Why is my fadeToggle looping on one certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I am trying to create three clickable divs, one to open, and two to close a popup window. One of the "close" divs works like a charm, however the other loops the `fadeToggle`. The looping class is `.exit` (upper left corner, grey box).
Please see JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/StudentEric/zx221ssy/

```
´$(".maincontainer, .opaquebg").hide();
 $("#orange, .exit, .opaquebg").click(function(){
 $(".maincontainer, .opaquebg").fadeToggle(500);
 });
 });´
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are binding the same event for `.opaquebg` and `.exit` and `.exit` is child of `.opaquebg`. So if you do not stop the `#orange` click event event, it is going to trigger the event twice just like what you are experiencing right now. Try

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

inside of your click event like:

```
$("#orange, .exit, .opaquebg").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".maincontainer, .opaquebg").fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zx221ssy/1/

As a side note, you do not need to `fadeToggle` your `.maincontainer` child element since you are already fade toggling your parent `.opaquebg`. So your code can look like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".opaquebg").hide();
  $("#orange, .exit, .opaquebg").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".opaquebg").fadeToggle(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: As a side note, if I didn't want a click on the .maincontainer to fadeToggle, just .opaquebg and .exit, would I add ´e.stopPropagation(!==.maincontainer)´?

Comment: not sure what do you mean. Please clarify the question.

Comment: When the div fades in (.opaquebg and .maincontainer along with .exit), I don't want a click on .maincontainer to hide all three classes. Just the exit square (grey box) and clicking the opaque area around the maincontainer is what I want to toggle the fade. I tried to include the not() selector but that didn't work.

Comment: Not a very experienced programmer (hence poor descriptive skills) so if you still need clarification let me know.

Comment: Then you need to move your `.maincontainer` section outside of the `.opaquebg`: http://jsfiddle.net/zx221ssy/12/. Also dont forget the upvote and mark as answer if this satisfies your question.

Comment: Rad! That definitely answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Oh and sorry, I have only level 1 reputation, it claims 15 is needed. Whenever I level up, however that is done, I shall return and vote up.